# How to enable the lazy-apps in uwsgi to use fork () in the code?

Tags: python, django-views, fork, uwsgi

I use Debian + Nginx + Django + UWSGI.

One of my function us **fork()** in the file **view.py** (the fork works well), then immediately written **return render (request, ...**

After the **fork()** the page loads for a long time and after that browser prints error - **"Web page not available»**. On the other hand the error doesn’t occur if i reload the page during loading (because i don’t launch the **fork()** again).

The documentation UWSGI there is -

> uWSGI tries to (ab)use the Copy On Write semantics of the **fork()** call whenever possible. By default it will fork after having loaded your applications to share as much of their memory as possible. If this behavior is undesirable for some reason, use the **lazy-apps** option. This will instruct uWSGI to load the applications after each worker’s **fork()**. Beware as there is an older options named **lazy** that is way more invasive and highly discouraged (it is still here only for backward compatibility)

I do not understand everything, and I wrote in a configuration option uWSGI lazy-apps: **lazy-apps: 1** in my **uwsgi.yaml**.

It does not help that I'm wrong?
What do I do with this problem?

P.S. other options besides **fork()** is that I do not fit ..

PP.S. Sorry, I used google translate ..

Answer (score 1):

use **lazy-apps = true** instead of 1

Comment: This can be a comment instead of an answer. Please, read the rules of the community and welcome :)